# Maximum recommended cpu wattage in a 1u chassis?

Tags: computer-building, workstation

I'm building a workstation for home use. I really want to use a 1u chassis. I'm worried about heat though. Is there a recommended maximum cpu wattage for 1u chassis, when not being liquid cooled, or in a cold server room? For example, I'm the cpu that I am going to use is the E3-1271 V3.

For those of you who are wondering why I'm looking at 1u chassis for home use. The workstation will only use 140 watts maximum. So I'm looking at a 1u psu that is only 250 watts from sea sonic.

Comment: Is the workstation going be in a room away from the user so that you do not have to be concerned with the amount of noise the fans will make? How many fans can you fit to the chassis you intend to use? Thin chassis=small fans=more noise than larger fans for the same airflow.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have not chosen a case. I was looking at iStarUSA. But that is as far as I got. So basically your saying that the noise gets pretty bad with small fans? -Thank you very much for your comment!

Comment: Along with the 1u chassis, you would likely be getting a 19" rackmount cabinet. There are some available which are intended to cut down the noise which escapes into the room, and then it is the heat dissipation capacity of the cabinet which you would have to investigate. If the motivation for getting a 1u chassis is what looks like a small size, remember that they are usually at least 19" deep, rather heavy, and only the front panel has any concern for aesthetics.